# Android App Widget - How To Create TextView Marquee On Two Separate Lines With Adjustable Scrolling Speeds?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, horizontal-scrolling, android-appwidget

I'm trying to create a widget with several different lines on it and want to set it to auto scroll (marquee) and have the ability to adjust the scrolling speed.  How can I accomplish this?

I tried using a TextView and was able to make it scroll on one line, but that's it.  I can't seem to adjust the speed of it or have two lines scrolling at the same time.

An example of this is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=huntsman.stocktickertapelite&hl=en

OR

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cousinHub.widget

Anyone have an idea of how they did it? (custom views?)

Thanks.

This is what I have so far:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <requestFocus 
                android:focusable="true" 
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:duplicateParentState="true" />
        </TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am getting the text from Java as setText file, and show in this screen

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line_dotted"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textColor="#0A2A1B"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </ScrollView>
```

Or You can try this without scrollview, the text will scroll when there is more than 5 ines

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/Comments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Submitbtn"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="Comments"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Comment: I thought you can't have scrollviews in an app widget?